# How to create a 3D mesh with Python?

Tags: python, 3d, mesh

I have a rectangular parallelepiped with three dimensions (X, Y, Z): 1 x 1 x 10. I want to create a mesh with 3 x 3 x 21 nodes and 2 x 2 x 20 finite elements which are 8-nodes solid elements with 2x2x2 integrating points. How can i do this with Python and collect the coordinates of all integrating points?

[image]

(photo's credits: Anton Zaicenco)

Thanks for your attention!

Comment: What exactly is your question? Do you want to know the formula to calculate the points? I guess this is pretty obvious and would be off-topic here. If you want to know how to store them, I guess a list of three-tuples or a numpy-array with shape (n,3) would be appropriate, depending on your further usage.

Comment: I want to know how to do some tricks like numpy.meshgrid and then print the coordinates of all the points.

Answer (score 2):

Although I am still not entirely sure what you want, here an example using `numpy.meshgrid` printing all nodes:

```
import numpy

x = numpy.linspace(0, 1, 3)
y = numpy.linspace(0, 1, 3)
z = numpy.linspace(0, 10, 21)
mesh = numpy.meshgrid(x, y, z)
nodes = list(zip(*(dim.flat for dim in mesh)))
for node in nodes:
    print(node)
```

Although this can also be done as three simple loops:

```
for x in numpy.linsapce(0, 1, 3):
    for y in numpy.linspace(0, 1, 3):
        for z in numpy.linspace(0, 10, 21):
            print((x, y, z))
```

For further information on the usage of `numpy.meshgrid` see the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html).